# Npm not installed?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I recently downloaded `node.js` from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org) and installed it correctly on windows, from `gitbash`. I ran `node -v`, it gave me a version number, but when I ran `npm -v`, I get bunch of error message like these;

> Internal/module/cjs/loader.js:330 Throw err;
>
> Error: cannot find module 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nom-registry-fetch\node_modules\fighy-pudding\index.js'.
>   Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

And other bunch of errors...

How do I fix these, please

Answer (score 1):

Npm is distributed with Node.js- which means that when you download Node.js, you automatically get npm installed on your computer. If it's not working in your case then try again or you need to install npm separately.
For installing you can follow the blog:-

```
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-node-js-npm-on-windows
```

OR

You can download the same from:-

```
https://nodejs.org/en/download/
```

I hope it would help!

Comment: Thanks for the replies but didnt solve my issue..... had to reinstall windows...lol